# how to show only particular array items detail in react native

Tags: arrays, react-native

I want to show the remaining fields in my array item only when clicking. But its showing all items details by clicking on one

```
<View>
{this.state.myarray.map((data) => (
  <View key={data.id}>
    <Text>{data.name}</Text>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.showDetails}>
      <Text>Show</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly it shows the details of all the items when you click one item. Well it because all items share state. You need to create a component that map will render each time, so each item will have its own state. So when the item is clicked, its own state changes, and that way only he will show more details.